# Group divisibility question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, divisibility

I have the following question which I can't make sense of, here is the entire question:

> If $G$ is a group, $b\in G, o(b)=k$ and $b^n = e$, show that $k|n$

What is $o(b)$? Please help.

Comment: $o(b)$ is the order of $b$, i.e., the least positive integer $k$ such that $b^k = e$.  Anyway, as a hint use the division algorithm and divide $k$ into $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$o(b)$ is generally taken to be the *least positive* integer $m$ such that $b^m = e$, and it appears that is how $o(b)$ is defined in the present question.  Granting this, and setting $k = o(b)$, we may use the Euclidean division algorithm in $\Bbb Z$ and hence write $n = qk + r$ with $0 \le r < k$.  Then

$e = b^n = b^{(qk + r)} = b^{qk}b^r = (b^k)^q b^r = e^q b^r = eb^r = b^r. \tag{1}$

If $r \ne 0$, (1) contradicts $o(b) = k$ since $r < k$.  Thus $r = 0$, $n = qk$ and so $k \mid n$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***